# Cakephp 2 - Use Auth-Component in another Component

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to access the AuthComponent in another component using

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class AccessComponent extends Object {

public function foo() {
    $this->user = $this->Auth->User();
}
```

But retrieve an error:

> Undefined property: AccessComponent::$Auth
>   [APP\Controller\Component\AccessComponent.php, line 21]

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. Also - In general: mind your casing. user() !== User()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `user` as a [static method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user) of `AuthComponent`

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
$this->user = AuthComponent::user();
```

OR include the component in `$components`:

```
class AccessComponent extends Component {
   public $components = array('Auth');

   public function foo() {
       $this->user = $this->Auth->user();
   }
}
```

Comment: adding `public $components = array('Auth');` to the component would also work. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use methodes for access to your User

**AuthComponent**

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

$this->user = AuthComponent::user();
```

**CakeSession**

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

$this->user = CakeSession::read("Auth.User");
```